# How to add elements to page at runtime

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm creating a demo web-app in angular for college and I want to click a `button` to add a new node to the dom tree. In JavaScript, I would use

```
document.getElementById('ticket-container').appendChild('app-ticket');
```

I can't seem to find an answer to this and I would have thought it would be straight-forward.

What's the best way to do this in angular 8?

```
*ngFor="let ticket of ticketcount; index as i;
```

Here's my parent component ts file:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

class Ticket {
  name: string;
  price: number;

  constructor(x: string, y: number){
    this.name = x;
    this.price = y;
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-purchase-tickets',
  templateUrl: './purchase-tickets.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./purchase-tickets.component.scss']
})

export class PurchaseTicketsComponent implements OnInit {
  total: number;
  ticketCount: number;

  constructor() {
   }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.total = 0;
    this.ticketCount = 0;
  }

  incrementTotal() {
    this.total += 5;
    this.ticketCount ++;
    this.renderNewTicket();
  }

  renderNewTicket() {
    //render ticket code here
  }
}
```

and the template file is:

```
<main id='ticket-container'>
  <app-ticket ></app-ticket>
  <button mat-icon-button aria-label="new ticket" id="add-ticket" (click)="incrementTotal()" >
    <mat-icon>add</mat-icon> 
  </button>
</main>

<p>Total: €{{total}}</p>
```

Comment: What does your UI look like? From what I understand, it seems you need to use an array to store items and then list them on the UI using an `*ngFor`

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in my comments, it seems you need to use an array to store items and then list them on the UI using an `*ngFor`

Here, give this a try:

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";

interface Ticket {
  name: string;
  price: number;
}

@Component({
  selector: "grid-list-overview-example",
  styleUrls: ["grid-list-overview-example.css"],
  templateUrl: "grid-list-overview-example.html"
})
export class GridListOverviewExample {
  tickets: Array<Ticket> = [];
  total: number;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.addTicket();
  }

  addTicket() {
    this.tickets.push({
      name: `Ticket ${this.tickets.length + 1}`,
      price: 10
    });
    this.calculateTotal();
  }

  calculateTotal() {
    this.total = this.tickets
      .map(ticket => ticket.price)
      .reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
  }
}
```

And in your template:

```
<main id='ticket-container'>
    <mat-grid-list cols="2" rowHeight="2:1">
        <mat-grid-tile *ngFor="let ticket of tickets">{{ ticket.name }}</mat-grid-tile>
    </mat-grid-list>

    <button mat-icon-button aria-label="new ticket" id="add-ticket" (click)="addTicket()" >
    <mat-icon>add</mat-icon> 
  </button>

  <p>Total: €{{total}}</p>
</main>
```

---

> Here's a [**Working Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ticketing-in-angular?file=app/grid-list-overview-example.html) for your ref.

Comment: Oh wow, thanks a lot! also noticed you used an interface instead of a class for tickets, good thinking. ;)

Comment: Happy to help. If the answer was what you were looking for, please consider marking the answer as a solution to close the loop. :)

Answer (score 0):

You are using *ngfor so store the values related to ticket in an array (array of ticket objects) and use that in template (with *ngfor). ticketCount is a number and *ngfor expect an array!
Add a method in TS file to handle click event of the button and in that append a new value to that array. The UI updates accordingly